# How to get the items and subitems in a listview?

Tags: delphi, vcl, listviewitem

I want to get all items and subitems in my listview,but all I get is "TlistItem"

Here's my code:

```
procedure TFrameAnalyzer.AddEntry(opcode:word;data:Array of byte;direction:byte);
begin
  MessageBox(0,PChar(sListView1.Items.Item[4].ToString),'',0);
end;
```

How do I get the name of the item as string and the name of it's 2 subitems?

Comment: I'm not sure, but is the winforms tag really appropriate? If (as I assume) you are using Delphi 2009 it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get the name of the item, because it has no name. It has a `Caption` though, and a `SubItems` property of type `TStrings`. All of this can easily be found in the Delphi documentation BTW.  Look into `TListItem` and `TListItems` classes.

So you could do something like

```
procedure TFrameAnalyzer.AddEntry(opcode:word;data:Array of byte;direction:byte);
var
  Item: TListItem;
  s: string;
begin
  Item := sListView1.Items.Item[4];
  s := Item.Caption + #13#10
    + '  ' + Item.SubItems[0] + #13#10
    + '  ' + Item.SubItems[1];
  MessageBox(0, PChar(s), nil, 0);
end;
```

All error handling omitted, you should certainly not access array properties in this way without checking first that the indices are valid.

Comment: Could make more readable (IMHO) by removing parentheses and comma separators, preceding items with "+ #13 +" and subitems with "+ '  '#13 +"

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment. I just wanted to make them stand out properly, not lump them into one code line.

Comment: I have one question,why the tag "Winforms" wouldn't be appropriate if I'm using Delphi 2009? Isn't the VCL in delphi winforms?

Comment: The "standard" VCL (not VCL.net) is a native code wrapper for the Windows API. Windows Forms is a managed code (.NET) wrapper for the Windows API. In fact, .NET was inspired by the VCL, having the same person involved in the creation of both. Wikipedia has the gist of it under "winforms" and "VCL". Delphi 2009 has nothing whatsoever to do with the creation of winforms apps. I'll retag accordingly.

Comment: @mghie: I never use "#10" in this context.  I know the relevance in file systems, but for display I've never needed anything other than #13.  Just interesting, that's all.