# Access ListView item text (FMX)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I have a TListView and when the user clicks on the image of an item (big green dot in picture below) i want to copy the item text ("russtest.cfg") and subitem text ("My Device, 1991") to display in a ShowMessage.  I can't find how to do it in C++ Builder but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148267/how-to-get-the-items-and-subitems-in-a-listview) shows how in Delphi.

[image]

Below is the code i've tried in the TListView's `ItemClickEx` method:

```
  TListItem* item;
  item = ListView1->Items->Item[ItemIndex];
  UnicodeString s;
  s = item->ToString();
  ShowMessage(s);
```

But it brings back this:

[image]

**EDIT 1:** Added the code i use to populate the ListView:

```
    TListViewItem* item2Add = Form1->ListView1->Items->Add();
    Form1->ListView1->BeginUpdate();
    item2Add->Text = mystring3;     // e.g. "russtest.cfg"
    item2Add->Detail = mystring2;   // e.g. "My Device, 1991"
    item2Add->ImageIndex = 1;  // big green dot
    Form1->ListView1->EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Try `item->Text` and `item->Detail`. Btw. the Delphi link is concerning a `VCL TListView`, not `FMX`.

Comment: If my previous comment did not help, then please show how the item (including all aspects) is originally made.

Comment: Hi Tom - when i changed to `item->Text` i get an error 'Text is not a member of TListItem'.  I'll add an EDIT 1 to my post to show how i populate the ListView in the first place.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need to typecast the `TListItem*` to `TListViewItem*`, then you can access its `Text` property:

```cpp
TListViewItem* item = static_cast<TListViewItem*>(ListView1->Items->Item[ItemIndex]);
String s = item->Text;
ShowMessage(s);
```

Comment: how to code this in Delphi?

Comment: @Haizhou `var item: TListViewItem; s: string; ... item := TListViewItem(ListView1.Items[ItemIndex]); s := item.Text; ShowMessage(s);`

Comment: thanks Remy. I will try it soon. Solved it by using ListView1.Items[ItemIndex].Data['Text4'].AsString . but this is a surely a bug for LiveBinding ListView. We should report somewhere.

Comment: I used ListView1.Items[ListView1.Selected.Index].Data['Text1'].AsString;  where Text1 is my text item in my ListView1. So by changing item name you can access  any item in this row selected. I just used this code on item click event.

Comment: @RaimondasLukosius `ListView1.Selected` returns the selected item, so using `Selected.Index` in `ListView1.Items[]` to get the same item is redundant.  Try `TListViewItem(ListView1.Selected).Data['Text1'].AsString`